# Assigning another instance of the Model to the ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to implement an MVVM UserControl used to edit information about a single class instance (e.g. an instance of a Person class). I have created a View, a ViewModel and a Model. When my application launches the View, the View automatically instantiates a ViewModel in its DataContext. The ViewModel is instantiated with a new instance of the Model class.

Now when I assign a different Person to the ViewModel.Source property the properties are not updated in the View (because the DataContext has not changed and I am not raising PropertyChanged events. Of course I could raise property changed events on all properties of the ViewModel class when a new Person instance is assigned. But is this appropriate? Is there no better way? Do I have to create a new ViewModel for each Person instance and then assign it to the View.DataContext?

This is what the 3 classes look like approximately:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PersonView" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:PersonViewModel x:Key="viewmodel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txLastName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Path=txLastName}" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```cs
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _source; 

    public Person Source
    {
        get
        { 
            if (_source == null) _source = new Person();
            return _source;
        }
        set
        { 
            _source = value; 
            //should I now raise property changed on each property?
        }
    }

    public String txLastName
    {
        get { return Source.LastName; }
        set
        { 
            Source.LastName = value; 
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("txLastName");
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the binding is structured in this way then yes, when you change `Source` you will need to raise property changed notifications for any properties that depend on it.  Note a potential shortcut that `RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty)` is usually interpreted as 'all properties changed'.

If there is no composition of properties in the ViewModel (i.e. all are simple delegation as in the example) and the properties of the model do not change (or, if they can change, the model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) then it may be simpler to bind directly to the model (e.g. `{Binding Path=Source.LastName}`).  This way, when `Source` changes all bindings that depend on `Source` will update.